# Word Automation closes existing instance of Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, automation, office-interop

I have an opened instance of Word (that was opened manually) containing an unsaved document. When I run:

```
_officeApp = new Word.Application();
```

my Word instance is closing the GUI and it disappears from my open apps list in Task Manager (I am using Windows 8). The document is lost because the automation is using that instance instead of creating a new one.

Is there a way to force new Word.Application(); to create a new instance and not reuse an existing one?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this shouldn't happen but I don't know the actual answer, just try this and let me know:

```
            private Object excelLock = new Object();                
            lock (wordLock)
            {
                officeApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            }
```